# How to port forward a minecraft server

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, minecraft

**Hi!**

I'm looking to port forward my Minecraft server so that I can play it with my friend who is on a different network.

I am aware that there are other questions on this topic, but they are all specific to certain modems.

My modem is a ZTE MF275R, which is missing some of the inputs on the other modems.

[Here is a reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vD1y.png)

IP: 192.168.0.100 (computer's private IP)
Port Range: 25565-25565
Protocol: TCP&UDP
Comment: minecraft

When I put these into my router and then Put my router's WAN IP address into minecraft, it gives me this error:

`io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused:`

If somebody could please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it that would be great.
Thanks in advance,
Lennon McLean

edit: When I put in my computer's local IP address I can join the server fine.

Comment: Why do you think the current configuration is wrong?

Comment: because of the error i added in an edit.

Comment: @LennonMcLean - You don’t have a public IP address, you have a private IP address behind a Enterprise NAT, you won’t be able to forward your port given your ISP’s configuration.  (There is no solution to your problem)

Comment: It would help if you forwarded the correct ports. [If you are running a minecraft server behind your router then you need to setup a port forward in order to allow your friends to connect.](https://portforward.com/minecraft/)

Comment: You are missing UDP: 19132-19133

Comment: @DavidPostill I added udp and it gives the same error

Comment: @Mokubai I know that. I said I put in the WAN IP (the one in the browser address bar) of my router into Minecraft.

Comment: @Ramhound: Doesn't look like CGNAT here, as the router's control panel is shown as accessible through a public address...

Comment: @grawity - The author indicates their public IP address is being detected as **192.168.0.100** which is an intranet subnet (private) not an internet subnet (public).

Comment: I would suggest looking into getting a dynamic DNS provider (i.e. DynDNS, No-IP, etc). This is because it's very possible that your WAN IP will change, breaking your remote connectivity. DDNS providers usually include a client that will refresh on a periodic basis and make sure your URL is pointing to the right place. It also has the benefit of having being easier for your users to remember.

Your configuration looks like it should work, assuming you have the server IP correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just discovered a cool service called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) which forwards any server running on a local computer (e.g. localhost:25565) to a URL that looks like: https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.ngrok.io for a web server, or tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:xxxxx for a different server.
For a minecraft server:

```
ngrok tcp 25565
```

Output:

```
your server is available at: x.tcp.ngrok.io:xxxxx
```